# Cplex Python API constraint definition

Tags: python, api, constraints, cplex

I have a working MIP model in cplex, however now I wanna model it in Cplex Python API and I am encountering some problems. More specific, I defined all my variables and I am pretty sure I did this correct as I added them in steps and first the model was working. However, now I wanna add the following constraint and I am not quite sure how to do this:

sum_c( l[c][t] ) = sum_b( y[b][t]*k[b] )

Hereby, l[c][t] are continuous variables and y[b][t] are binary variables, k[b] are parameters.

I added this constraint in the following way but I know (as I already solved the problem in cplex) that the outcomes are not correct:

```
for j in range(nrtime):
    thevars=[]
    thecoefs=[]
    for b in range(nrbid):
        thevars.append(y[b][j])
        thecoefs.append(k[b])
    for i in range(nrev):
        thevars.append(l[i][j])
        thecoefs.append(-1)
    c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(thevars, thecoefs)], senses="E", rhs=[0])
```

I'm thinking my mistake is in the use of my for loops but I am not quite sure. 
Can anyone tell me my mistake? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: You say you have a working model in cplex.  What do you mean by that?  Which API are you using?  Or, do you have an LP file that you feed to the interactive?  Regardless of that, I'd suggest calling `c.write("prob.lp")` in your Python program to see what your problem looks like (e.g., after your `for` loop above or immediately before you call `solve`).  That should give you a good idea of where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I indeed called c.write("prob.lp"), and I managed to find that the mistake was not in this constraint but in another (much easier) constraint, which I did not expect at all. I already had the working model in the ILOG IBM Cplex Optimization Studio and the two objective values now coincide!